# Extract characters in between Special characters using stringstream in C++

Tags: c++, json, parsing, stringstream

I am getting a JSON `{"Success":true,"Error":null,"Result":null}` object from an API and im using String stream to extract the data i need. This object is been passed as `temp` in the code below

I know there are libraries available to handel JSON but i want to parse it without using libraries.

i had refered [How to deserialize json string in c++ without using any third party library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291882/how-to-deserialize-json-string-in-c-without-using-any-third-party-library). It works well untill i come across special characters.

```
                std::stringstream ss(temp); //Using Json response stream
                const unsigned int BUFFERSIZE = 1087;
                //temporary buffer
                char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
                memset(buffer, 0, BUFFERSIZE * sizeof(char));
                std::pair<std::string, std::string> returnValue;
                while (ss.peek() != '{')
                {
                    ss.ignore();
                }
                while (ss.peek() != '}' && value == "")
                {
                    ss.get(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, '\"');
                    ss.ignore();
                    ss.get(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, '\"');
                    ss.ignore();
                    returnValue.first = buffer;
                    ss.get(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, ':');
                    ss.ignore();
                    ss.get(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, ',');
                    ss.ignore();
                    returnValue.second = buffer;
                    cout << returnValue.second;
                    if (returnValue.first == "Success") {
                        value = buffer;
                    }
                }
```

I am trying to extract the value `true` which is in between `":"` and `","` but insted im getting an empty string.

Am i missing something.?

Comment: Please note that the same `buffer` is passed to all those `get` calls.

Comment: It works if you remove `ss.get(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, ':');`, but I'm not sure why...

Comment: It appears that `ss.get(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, ':');`, when the first character in the ss is `:`, doesn't remove *nothing* (as it ought to), it eats the entire contents of the ss, colons and all. This does not seem specific to ':', it happens if we use another character. Is it possible that this is a bug in `stringstream::get`?

Comment: if you  "want to parse it without using libraries" then do not "i had refered ....."

Answer (score 0):

When the following line is executed:

```cpp
ss.get(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, ':');
```

The content of `ss` is something like `":true, ..."`, meaning that the very first character, ready to be extracted, is indeed `':'`.

The class `std::stringstream` inherits from `std::basic_istream` the function `get`. We can find a reference documentation at [en.cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) (emphasis mine):

> Extracts character or characters from stream.
> All versions behave as [UnformattedInputFunctions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnformattedInputFunction). After constructing and checking the sentry object, these functions perform the following:
> [...]
> 4) Reads characters and stores them into the successive locations of the character array whose first element is pointed to by s. Characters are extracted and stored until any of the following occurs:
>
> - count-1 characters have been stored
> - end of file condition occurs in the input sequence (setstate(eofbit) is called)
> - **the next available input character c equals delim,** as determined by `Traits::eq(c, delim)`. **This character is not extracted (unlike `basic_istream::getline()`)**
>
> **If no characters were extracted, calls setstate(failbit).** In any case, if count>0, a null character (CharT() is stored in the next successive location of the array.

All the successive operations on that stream will fail, as long as `failbit` is set.

You could either use [`clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) to recover or implement a completely different algorithm.